# Find the image of $A=(-2,1) \times [-2,2)$ under the function $f(x,y)=x^2y$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I have function $f(x,y)=x^2y$ and I have to find image $f[A]$ where $A=(-2,1) \times [-2,2)$

we have that $-2 < x < 1$ and $-2\le y<2$

$0 \le x^2 < 4 $

I claim that the image of $f[A]=(-8,8)$ to show that

$f[A] \subseteq (-8,8)$ we need to notice that $-8<x^2y<8$ since $0 \le x^2<4$ and $-2 \le y<2$ so multiplying we get the desired ineqaulity

I have problem with showing $(-8,8) \subseteq f[A]$ to show that I need to take $t \in (-8,8)$ and taking $y=-2$ we have $t \in (-8,0)$ so $f(x,-2)=t$

$-2x^2=t\in (-8,0)$

$x= -\sqrt{\frac{t}{-2}} \in (-2,0)$ or $x=\sqrt{\frac{t}{-2}} \in(0,2)$ and I have problem what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $0\in f[A]$. Suppose now that $t\in(0,8)$. Choose any $u\in(t,8)$, and set $y=\frac{u}4$; then $0<y<2$. Moreover, $0<\frac{t}y=\frac{4t}u<4$, so $\sqrt{\frac{t}y}<2$. Let $x=-\sqrt\frac{t}y$; then $\langle x,y\rangle\in A$, and $f(x,y)=x^2y=t$.

The case $t\in(-8,0)$ is easier, since you can start by setting $y=-2$; what must $x$ be in that case?

Comment: how did you know to set $y=\frac{u}{4}$  ?

Comment: @Mario: I know that with $x\in(-2,1)$ I can get any value of $x^2$ in $[0,4)$. Once I’ve chosen my $y\in[0,2)$, I can get any $x^2y$ in $[0,4y)$. That means that $4y$ has to be some number bigger than $t$, so I give $4y$ the name $u$ for short, choose it to be bigger than $t$, and of course then $y=\frac{u}4$. Choosing $u<8$ ensures that $y<2$. (To be honest, I didn’t think it out in such detail at the time, but that’s the result of many years of experience.)

Answer (score 0):

Prescribing $g\left(x,y\right)=xy$ on $B=\left[0,4\right)\times\left[-2,2\right)$
gives $g\left[B\right]=f\left[A\right]$.

This actually is replacing $x^{2}$ with domain $\left(-2,1\right)$
by the 'less complex' $x$ with domain $\left[0,4\right)$.

For $t\in\left(-8,8\right)$ find some $r\in\left(0,4\right)$ s.t.
$\left|t\right|<2r$.

Then $t=g\left(r,s\right)$ for $s=\frac{t}{r}\in(-2,2)$.